# MySQL: Is there an operator to identify unique values?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, operators

I want to update the column 'status' in a dataframe 'Enrollments' that references another 'visitID' column, but I want the values within 'status' to be as follows:

When there are 2 or more Id's that are the same in 'visitID' column - set that value in 'status' as 'returning' and when there is only one unique value in 'visitID' - set that respective value in status as 'new'.

Here is what I tried:

```
UPDATE Enrollments
SET Status = (CASE WHEN VisitID IS UNIQUE THEN 'New'  ELSE 'Returning' END)
```

I am receiving this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'.

Comment: If there are 3 rows with the same visitID then one of them should stay New and another 2 rows should become Returning?

Comment: Storing such computed values tend to lead to data inconsistency. Can't you create a view instead - will always have up-to-date data!

Answer (score 1):

You could make it like this

As you can see the subquery count the occurences of visitID and depending on the number sets the status

```
CREATE tABLe Enrollments (VisitID int, Status varchar(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO Enrollments values (1,NULL),(1,NULL),(2,NULL)
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
UPDATE Enrollments
SET Status = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Enrollments) e1 WHERE e1.VisitID = Enrollments.VisitID) = 1  THEN 'New'  ELSE 'Returning' END
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM Enrollments
```

| VisitID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Returning |
| 1 | Returning |
| 2 | New |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Za1R60Qd)